# The [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] become private in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, uniqueidentifier

Apple doesn't allowed to add application to the app store that used the [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] because the property become private in iOS SDK 6.0

What are the Alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

- (NSString*)deviceId {
    NSString *udidString;

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        udidString = [defaults objectForKey:@"udidKey"];
        if (!udidString) {
            CFUUIDRef identifierObject = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
            // Convert the CFUUID to a string
            udidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, identifierObject);
            [defaults setObject:udidString forKey:@"udidKey"];
            [defaults synchronize];
            CFRelease((CFTypeRef) identifierObject);
        }

    } else {
        udidString = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    }
    return udidString;
}
```

if gets warning on the line: `udidString = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];` it means the Xcode SDK is **less than 6.0**

(**Xcode 4.3** contains iOS SDK 5.1, **Xcode 4.5** contains iOS SDK 6.0)

to update Xcode iOS SDK:

1. simply download the newest Xcode available on App Store (Apple doesn't give an option to download only the SDK).
2. if want to keep current Xcode version just:

   - download the newest Xcode version.
   - copy iOS SDK Library from :

**newestXcode.app**/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

to

**oldXcode.app**/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/

Reopen old Xcode and thats it!

Comment: Though you can not use Device UDID in your application because its completely banned by Apple, otherwise your app will be rejected, i have posted details regarding it, you can read it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469566/invalid-application-binary/16475078#16475078)

Answer (score 0):

you can use/create "your own" UDID:

```
+(NSString *)getUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueId = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString * uuidString = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueId);
    CFRelease(newUniqueId);

    return uuidString;
}
```

You should keep in mind that this method will produce a different id on every call so you should persist it some how, thus it is not an identical alternative to the UDID, but for most uses it is even better like that.

Comment: Thats what i did! (case curr iOS version < 6.0) but method CFUUIDCreateString(x,y) return different id for each call. so the best thing to do is to save the first call for the method in NSUserDefaults dictionary.(NSUserDefaults parameters saved after close the app and open again).

Comment: @evya: 1. I don't see a reason to use the deprecated UDID in < 6.0, and a custom one for > 6.0; just use the custom one for all. 2. The question was "What are the Alternatives?", you can persist it however you want.. 3. I should have maybe commented on your answer, but it seemed that posting a clean answer with the only code relevant to the question would be more useful for answer seekers.